# Is it possible to sandbox Wine in a way that mitigates all security risks from running Windows apps/games and having Wine installed?

Tags: debian, security, wine, sandbox, emulation

And if that is more or less possible, how can it be done? Using `firejail` is [probably part of it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60852/233262) but not the full story.

I'd like to install Wine to be able to play Windows games that don't have native GNU/Linux support on my Debian11/KDE machine with Wayland. I don't trust officially released closed-source game code plus just having Wine installed could also introduce some new vulnerabilities (see for example [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49255/risks-disadvantages-associated-with-wine)).

---

For example, is it possible to create a virtual machine (along with firejail and some specific firejail-profile adjustments) for gaming with no substantial loss of performance? For example, by using [VFIO&QEMU](https://gist.github.com/0chroma/ed9590f4c79daaeb482c2419f74ed897) / [PCI passthrough via OVMF](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF) (is there any preconfigured tool ready to be used?). [Somehow using docker](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191886/how-can-i-sandbox-a-wine-application-on-linux/191895#191895) or a [LXC container, chroot, or creating a new user](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-sandbox-wine-4175681479/) may also be part of this.

Which way would be best (or rather meets this requirement) security- and performance-wise and how to take care of remaining new vulnerabilities?

I'd like to use Lutris (and/or PlayOnLinux).

Comment: You need to evaluate your threat model if you don't feel comfortable running closed-source games, but still do it, and even try to get it to run on another OS. Too broad of a question, will attract opinionated answers ("best for security and performance" isn't specific or measurable).

Comment: I'm not doing it so far but would probably like to if it was possible to mitigate Wine security issues which this question is about. I don't try to get it run on another OS, I'll stay with Debian. It's measurable / not opinion-based in terms of that it should solve all known newly introduced security vulnerability, maybe I wrote it badly but it's about _any_ way that meets this requirement - I do suspect that currently there's only one or fewer basic ways to achieve that.