# How to use wine with more security?

Tags: security, wine, malware, sandbox

After installing Wine I found that there is a z drive that has direct access to root folder. I have seen many threads and news about virus affecting a linux system through wine. How do I make it more secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run wine via `firejail`.

Some examples and discussion: https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/2219

Comment: Is this the most secure option [or are there better ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714165/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-wine-in-a-way-that-mitigates-all-security-risks-from-r) without large performance drop? If you use it only for games does it help creating [a new user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wine#Running_Wine_under_a_separate_user_account)? How can one [use firejailed Wine in Lutris](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues/4556) (for games)?

Comment: Firejail shouldn't incur a visible performance drop unless you've got an ancient CPU. Using a separate user is a good option but it's quite an inconvenient one.

Comment: Deleting `z:` from Wine does literally nothing. Windows applications can run Linux binaries directly even when z: does not exist. It used to work in the past (over three years ago) but then Wine developers dropped this feature as a security theater.

Comment: Do you have a link concerning deleting `Z:`? It's probably irrelevant whether one does that if it's sandboxed with firejail to only access allowed dirs anyway. Performance drop was only referring to other options _besides_ firejail. Is it maybe possible to run an app as the new restricted user from the root user to make it more convenient?

Comment: `z:` -> https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25537 The feature was dropped 12 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

[sandwine](https://github.com/hartwork/sandwine) could be an alternative to firejail for Wine. Its readme has details on the underlying threat model and what is exposed to the application by default.